# Retrieve current user's children data : Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In our app, we have to retrieve the names of the diaries under the current user and display them in a `ListView`.

We have referred to a number of questions similar to our one, but none of them came handy. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

In the Firebase structure shown in the image:

1. A user can have any number of diaries (say user in this pic has 3
   diaries, namely Hyderabad, Dubai and Toronto
2. Under every diary, there are images along with experience of the
   user.
3. Aim is to get just the diary names of the user under consideration

Under each of these diaries, there are images (we are able to retrieve the images into a `listview` ; a separate one displayed in a fragment)

The expected output is - A new `ListView` that should be populated with the diary names - Hyderabad, Chennai and Bangalore [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOJka.jpg)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F1Ro.jpg)

Comment: Instead of describing how you database looks like, please add a JSON file or atleas a screenshot of it. Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I've added the screenshot

Comment: Please add a more detailed one, including the content of your `Dubai`, `Toronto` etc nodes and indicate what is the exact data you want to gey.

Comment: yeah. Here is the updated one.

Comment: And you want to get all images of a user within a single location (Dubai) or within all locations?

Comment: Not the images. Just the names of all diaries under a user

Comment: Within a single city (Dubai), or all cities?

Comment: just the names Dubai, Hyderabad, etc. How to retrieve those names?

Comment: Which one of the [following names](https://ibb.co/dj37kQz) you want to get, those highlighted in red or green?

Comment: the ones highlighted in red

Comment: Please see my answer below and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your last comment, to get all city names in a `ListView`, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("image").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> cities = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String cityName = ds.getKey();
            cities.add(cityName);
        }
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cities);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result in your `ListView` will be:

```
Dubai
Hyderabad
Toronto
```

Comment: It's Working! Thank you so much!

Comment: Now I've tried to use a custom class and custom adapter (So that diary names are displayed in the list along with a diary photo)..But, the app is crashing

Comment: That sounds as another problem, which basically cannot be answered in a comment. In order to follow the rules of this community, please post another fresh question, so me and other Firebase developers can help you.